# Is it possible to detect what asp:button has been clicked in the Page_init event?

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP:Button with an onclick event. Is it possible to detect that this button has been clicked on the Page_Init event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the ClientId of the button, you can check in the Request object. Otherwise, no. At the Page_Init stage, the page and child controls are only being loaded, and events will be handled only later.

```
Request.Form["_EVENTTARGET"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `Request.Form["_EVENTTARGET"]`, it should hold the ID of the control that fired the PostBack.

Answer (score 0):

The "button1" is the client id of your button. If Request.Params["button1"] does not return null then "button1" was clicked.

Comment: ClientID (id attribute in html murkup) is not name attribute that is passed during submit.